# C# URL Handling to allow either separate sites or virtual directories?

Tags: c#

I've got a question more for my own learning experience than anything as I've already found a solution, or two to be more specific.

The issue was that I have a web service I connect to with an application, but the web service can be deployed different ways, IE, IIS Virtual Directories, or Separate Sites. Obviously, these will have an impact on the URL. The URL in this case gets pulled from a configuration file wherever the application is installed, so the application has to be able to handle whatever gets pulled from there.

I wrote a quick chunk in a sample console example. The first method doesn't work in the case of virtual directories which is where the issue arises. The other 2 methods return the correct result, I'm just curious, if there would be a reason why one wouldn't simply replace string over using LastIndexOf, and if maybe there's another solution?

```
Uri SiteNameUrl = new Uri("http://SiteName.test.com/PackageDlService.aspx");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Scenario 1: {0}",SiteNameUrl));

String path = SiteNameUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
String uriStr = String.Format(@"{0}/SiteName/Packages/{1}/CurrentPackage.zip", path, "1.0");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Method 1 (Broken): {0}", uriStr));

path = SiteNameUrl.ToString().Replace("/PackageDlService.aspx","");
uriStr = String.Format(@"{0}/Packages/{1}/CurrentPackage.zip", path, "1.0");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Method 2: {0}", uriStr));

path = SiteNameUrl.ToString().Substring(0, SiteNameUrl.ToString().LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '/', '\\' }) + 1);
uriStr = String.Format(@"{0}Packages/{1}/CurrentPackage.zip", path, "1.0");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Method 3: {0}", uriStr));

Console.WriteLine(); // add a line break between examples

Uri SiteNameUrl1 = new Uri("http://www.test.com/SiteName/PackageDlService.aspx");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Scenario 2: {0}", SiteNameUrl1));

String path1 = SiteNameUrl1.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
String uriStr1 = String.Format(@"{0}/SiteName/Packages/{1}/CurrentPackage.zip", path1, "1.0");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Method 1 (Broken): {0}", uriStr1));

path1 = SiteNameUrl1.ToString().Replace("/PackageDlService.aspx","");
uriStr1 = String.Format(@"{0}/Packages/{1}/CurrentPackage.zip", path1, "1.0");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Method 2: {0}", uriStr1));

path1 = SiteNameUrl1.ToString().Substring(0, SiteNameUrl1.ToString().LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '/', '\\' }) + 1);
uriStr1 = String.Format(@"{0}Packages/{1}/CurrentPackage.zip", path1, "1.0");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("URL Method 3: {0}", uriStr1));
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why you would need this. Simply configure the full URI.

Comment: Easier said there's a ton of other areas in the application doing similar things calling different pages. Changing the global setting would require fixing them all. I agree it would be the better solution, but requires a lot more work and extensive testing which is not my call